# How to control zorder and clipping with mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.mark_inset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In a plot with inset axes, I want to mark the inset using mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.mark_inset. However, I'm running into trouble controlling the zorder and clipping of the resulting lines marking the inset. The inset axes are set to `zorder=4`, and I'm using:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_tight_layout(False)
ax = fig.gca()

x = np.arange(4500.0, 10000.0)
ax.plot(x, 700-x/20.0+20*np.sin(x/8.0), label="Skylines")


from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition, mark_inset, inset_axes

inset_ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], zorder=4, frameon=True)
inset_ax.set_axes_locator(InsetPosition(ax, [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]))

inset_ax.plot(x, 700-x/20.0+20*np.sin(x/8.0))

inset_ax.set_xlim(8800, 8850)
inset_ax.set_ylim(230, 285)
# inset_ax.set_ylim(100, 600)

mark_inset(ax, inset_ax, loc1=2, loc2=3, linewidth=0.7, fc="None", ec='k', alpha=0.4, clip_on=True, zorder=3)

ax.axhline(y=300, c='r', label="Test")

leg = ax.legend(ncol=1, loc='upper center', frameon=True, framealpha=1.0)
leg.set_zorder(5)

plt.show()
```

which, for two different cases in y limits, results in

[image]

[image]

The unwanted behaviour here is that the inset lines appear across the inset axes (while the line marked Test is placed nicely behind the inset axes), and outside of the main axes (and through the legend), respectively. I would have expected the `zorder` and `clip_on` arguments to fix this, but they don't seem to have an effect.

Comment: `zorder` isn't global. It's *per* axes. If you want to provide a test case (see [mcve]) I'm happy to look further into this.

Comment: That would make sense, I updated my question with the code that I'm using. I guess my question then is how to control `zorder` and clipping behaviour between different axes.

Comment: why not use `loc1=1, loc2=4,` in `mark_inset`?

Comment: Of course I could do this here, but in a generalised case where I may not know the precise location/size of the inset axes it can get tricky choosing the 'right' `loc1`, `loc2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1**

`zorder` is evaluated on a per axis base. Since the connector lines are added to the inset axes, they will always be on top of the axes background. An option is to remove them from the inset axes and add them to the original one.

**Case 2**

The connectors are explicitely not clipped in the matplotlib source code, because as part of the inset axes you would not ever want them to be clipped by the inset axes.

However, if they are part of the original axes, you can set clipping to on again.

**In total**

```
ret = mark_inset(ax, inset_ax, loc1=2, loc2=3, linewidth=0.7, fc="None", ec='k', alpha=0.4)

for bc in ret[1:]:
    bc.remove()
    ax.add_patch(bc)
    bc.set_zorder(4)
    bc.set_clip_on(True)
```

[image]
[image]